# GA filter - regex capture group to match query param

Tags: regex, google-analytics, analytics

I've been trying to get a GA regex filter to alias a custom query paramater as `utm_campaign`. For example, we have this url:

```
https://example.com?open=1&sid=123456
```

In order to track `sid` as `utm_campaign`, I've created a "Search and Replace" filter, with the following regex:

> **Search String**: `(\?|&)sid=`

> **Replace**: `$1utm_campaign=`

This is valid Regex, and works in Regexr. However it's not rewriting the parameter in GA.

Does anyone know of any reason this wouldn't work? Are their exceptions to what regex can be used? I can't seem to find any mention of this in the docs.

Also, does anyone know whether this would actually be recorded as a `utm_campaign` param? If I change a non-default param to be `utm_campaign`, does GA correctly recognise this?

Many thanks for any help in advace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more investigation, it seems like Darrellwan is correct, the `utm_campaign` params are recognised by GA prior to filters being applied, which is a shame!

To answer the regex question, I ended up doing this:

[image: filter regex]

As is mentioned in another answer, GA uses `$A1` / `$B1` etc to handle regex match / replace in the advanced section.

Just in case anyone else is looking for an answer to this.

It looks like we'll need another solution to our `sid` param issue though.

Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't found complete answer for you, but you can check this blog:

> https://www.optimizesmart.com/regular-expression-guide-for-seos/

They are using named variables and they refer them as $A1 and $B1. So that might give you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about we can change the parameter to utm_campaign and it will show on report after the hit is sent to GA already.

Maybe the better way is you can changed the parameter before the hit send to GA in GTM or using JavaScript.

If you are using GTM to send GA.
You can see the setting here:
Add Field To Set campaignMedium : {{yourVariableToGetSid}}
And Add Variable {{yourVariableToGetSid}}

[image]

[image]